# Restlet css and javascript files

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml, restlet

WebContent
   - resources
       - css
           - style.css
WEB-INF
   - index.html

```
public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    router.attach("/", IndexResource.class); 
    return router;
}
```

The IndexResource executes an HTML Respresentation (index.html)

In my index.html I have specified a css file. The problem is that it cannot be found.

```
  <link href="/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I think `/resources/css/style.css` is going via restlet and not the actual file path. How do I stop the resources folder executing as a servlet (restlet)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651019/cant-get-resource-files-in-my-template-files-using-restlet-and-freemarker

Comment: try making your link relative "resources/css/style.css" instead of absolute

Answer (score 1):

Must your css file need to be served by Restlet? If so, you should consider using the Directory class as described below (in your application class):

```
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    (...)
    router.attach("/resources", new Directory(getContext(), "file://<STATIC_DIR>"));
}
```

In this case you need to have css/style.css under the  folder.

Hope it helps you.
Thierry

Comment: I would prefer it not to be served by restlet but it always goes through as a servlet. I'm not sure how to stop it.All I attach is:

router.attach("/", IndexResource.class);

Comment: When you stay <STATIC_DIR> do you mean:
C:/Users/<MyUsername>/rest/webapp/ or C:/Users/<MyUsername>/rest/webapp/resources